# redirect htaccess from lowercase letters to uppercase magento using .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

redirect htaccess lowercase to uppercase after

```
http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=
```

**From:** http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=apple

**To:** http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=APPLE

thanks

Comment: Any get solution?